# How do I keep smartgwt from polluting the window namespace?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, smartgwt

I have existing javascript in a project that creates a 'Calendar' object. The object is a member of `window`.

When I added smartgwt to my project, the original Calendar object was overwritten by a smartclient calendar (ISC_Calendar) packaged in smartgwt.

Using a browser-based JS debugger, I found that all the JS objects from smartgwt were contained both in `window` and in `window.isc`. I definitely don't want them all at window level because many of them have generic names like Calendar.

The offending file in my case is ISC_Calendar.js, which ends up in war/<projectname>/sc/modules after a gwt compile. It calls the following line: `isc.ClassFactory.defineClass("Calendar","Canvas","DataBoundComponent");`

GWT compiled location: war/projectname/sc/modules/ISC_Calendar.js
Jar location: com.smartclient public/sc/modules/ISC_Calendar.js
Src location: can't find it

I suppose I can just change the javascript file in the jar I'm using, but that doesn't really solve the larger problem. I don't want to worry about running into namespace issues down the road

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set

```
var isc_useSimpleNames = false;
```

in script tag before any SmartClient components are loaded. This way SC will register classes only in isc.* namespace.

Comment: Well it seems that after enabling this option I'm getting errors when I'm trying to invoke DynamicForm.getValues() method... Probably it  should be reported to Isomorphic as the error comes from SmartClient not SmartGWT.

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to rename smartgwt's Calendar to Calendar2.

First, check out the source code for smartgwt. See here: http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/wiki/BuildingFromSVN

Then, in the source code, open up trunk/main/src/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/calendar/Calendar.java. Find this code snippet:

```
public Calendar(){
    scClassName = "Calendar";
}
```

And replace "Calendar" with Calendar2.

Now compile the source. Consult this link again to help you compile: http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/wiki/BuildingFromSVN.

Take the resulting smartgwt.jar and open it up in a jar editor. Navigate to `com.smartclient public/sc/modules/ISC_Calendar.js` and open it. Find this code snippet:

```
isc.ClassFactory.defineClass("Calendar","Canvas","DataBoundComponent");
```

And replace "Calendar" with Calendar2.

Next, in the same file, do a find and replace. Replace `isc.Calendar` with `isc.Calendar2`. Also do the find and replace in ISC_Core.js.

Now save the jar. The calendar should be functional and the window.Calendar namespace will be untouched.